# glVertexAttribPointer, interleaved elements and performance / cache friendliness

Tags: c, performance, caching, opengl, gpu

So, in the course of writing a model loader for a 3D scene I'm working on, I've decided to pack the vertex, texture and normal data like so:

```
VVVVTTTNNN
```

for each vertex, where V = vertex coordinate, T = UV coordinate, and N = normal coordinate.  When I pass this data on to the vertex shader for my scene, I make three glVertexAttribPointer calls, like so:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_VERTEX, 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 10, group->vertices.data);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_VERTEX);

glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_NORMAL, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 10, group->normals.data);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_NORMAL);

glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_UV_COORDINATES, 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 10, group->uvcoordinates.data);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_UV_COORDINATES);
```

Each of the group pointers being passed refer to the beginning position in the shared vertex data  block where that vertex type starts:

```
group->vertices.data == data
group->uvcoordinates.data == &data[4]
group->normals.data == &data[7]
```

Part of the reason for me interleaving this data was to program for cache friendliness and minimize data being sent to the card.  ( NOTE: This is not for a realistic performance bottleneck.  I'm investigating the optimization because I want to learn more about programming to address these sort of concerns. ) However, for the life of me, I can't imagine how GL would be able to infer that the 3 different pointers refer to offset positions within the same larger data block, and thereby make the necessary optimization to avoid copying the data once it has already been copied.   Furthermore, since I'm only ensuring data locality in system memory ( and don't really have any guarantees on how that data is going to be organized on the GPU ), I'm only really optimizing for the case where I access any of these vertices outside of GL.  Is that right?  Are these optimizations mostly useless, or will providing data in this manner help minimize the data transfer to the GPU / prevent cache misses when iterating over vertex data in the vertex shader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL is just an API, the intelligence lies in the driver. Anyway the problem is actually rather simple to implement: For every Vertex Attribute you got a starting memory address and when calling glDrawArrays or glDrawElements one looks for the largest index found. That defines the upper bound of the range.

Then you sort the vertex attributes starting addresses and for each address check if it range overlaps with any other vertex attribute range. You find the contiguous regions and copy those.

In the case of Vertex Buffer Objects it's even simpler since you already copied stuff to OpenGL ready for processing.

Comment: True enough, didn't even think about sorting the addresses.  And yeah, absolutely re: VBOs - just curious for different approaches. Thanks!